# SQL Server bcp with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I'm struggling with `bcp`. If I run the following SQL

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select a.displayname, a.samaccountname, a.mail, a.title, a.givenname, a.sn from web_repository.dbo.activedirectory a ORDER BY displayname" queryout "C:\phonegapdownload\test.dat" -N -S IISSERVER -T '
```

it works fine, however if I run this

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "EXEC SelectAllFromADNoJoin" queryout "C:\phonegapdownload\test.dat" -N -S IISSERVER -T '
```

which has the exact same SQL in it, it throws an error

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 2812

// not sure where I got this error from

It's running on SQL Server 2008 R2

Can anyone help?

I have checked that SQL Server allows remote connections and that tcpip is enabled

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
>   SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired

Comment: Those are two completely different errors. The first says a stored procedure can't be found, the second just indicates your server is unreachable. Obviously, you'll want to fix the second condition before fixing the first...

Comment: Yes, could you try again and write the exact console input and output for both cases? As it is now, it's a complete mystery what exactly is your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the full text of the error message would help. Error 2812 is "Could not find stored procedure". You will want to specify the `-d` option to specify your database, or use a quoted name (`MyDB.dbo.SelectAllFromADNoJoin`).